# Have a dataframe but need to make a barplot in python

Tags: python

Hi I have a very big dataframe, below is a snapshot. I want to calculate target %  split across various worker type and plot  bar graph (see attached picture)

```
 Worker type        TARGET  
0   Working               1      
1   State servant         0      
2   Pensioner             1      
3   Working               0     
4   Commercial associate  1      
5   State servant         0      
6   Commercial associate  0    
7   Pensioner             1     
8   Working               1      
9   Working               0
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = df[['Worker type']].plot(kind='bar', title ="Worker Type", figsize=(15, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12)
ax.set_xlabel("Worker", fontsize=12)
ax.set_ylabel("Count", fontsize=12)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df.groupby('Worker type').count().plot.bar(y='TARGET')
```

[image]